# On `blkid`'s `-O` option

Tags: filesystems, partition, libblkid

I was investigating blkid options and have trouble understanding the `-O` option.

```
user@host :~ $ > blkid --help | grep -E -- '-O'
 -O, --offset <offset>      probe at the given offset
```

What is this "offset" ?

For reference, On a virtual machine (with VirtualBox) with a VDI disk of 8GB, the biggest offset I can set before receiving the error message `invalid offset argument: [...] : Numerical result out of range` is :

```
[rootfs]# blkid -O 18446744073709551615
```

And it gives the same output as with `blkid` alone.

I first thought this would be the total number of sectors or bytes, but this above number does not correspond at all with either.

Comment: That's the largest 64-bit signed integer.

Comment: unsigned, sorry.

Comment: Oh you're right of course ! Thanks for the info :). So I guess this is unrelated to the size of the disk ? Besides, do you happen to know what the offset is ?

Answer (score -1):

This option doesn't make any sense if you don't specify a device to work on. In a perfect world `blkid -O 18446744073709551615` should just print something like,`"-O offset requires an argument"` and exit but it doesn't. You may file a bug report here https://bugz.fedoraproject.org/util-linux

From the man page:

```
-O, --offset offset
    Probe at the given offset (only useful with --probe).
    This option can be used together with the --info option.
```

This option won't work if not used properly with other **required** arguments.

Here's its output when used properly:

```
blkid -O 18446744073709551615 /dev/sda
/dev/sda: PTUUID="01abcdef" PTTYPE="dos"
```

It cannot actually read anything by this offset (it's 2^64-1), so it's reading from offset 0.